# Write a program that displays all the numbers from 100 to 1000, ten per line, that are divisible by 5 and 6

Tags: java

Write a program that displays all the numbers from 100 to 1000, ten per line, that are divisible by 5 and 6.

this is my program:

```
for (int i =100; i<= 1000; i++){

    if(i % 5==0 && i % 6==0)
        System.out.print(i +" ");

    if (i %10==0){
        System.out.println();

}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? Are you having a problem with the code that you've posted?

Comment: And what's the problem (apart the random formatting) ?

Comment: i need it 10 per line . but i cant let it show 10 per line..it appears everything in one line..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't really use modulo division here because you aren't keeping track of the number of times you have printed a number. Simply add a counter, and place a new line every time that counter is equal to 10.

For example:

```
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=100;i<=1000; i++) {
        if(i % 5==0 && i % 6==0) {
            System.out.print(i +" ");
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter==10) {
            System.out.println();
            counter=0;
        }
```

**Corrected for cross system compatibility**

Version without counter (wont work for all sets of numbers)

```
    for(int i=100;i<=1000; i++) {
        if(i % 5==0 && i % 6==0) 
            System.out.print(i +" ");
        if(i!=100 && (i - 100) % 300 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println();`  For cross platform compatibility don't use hard-coded "newline" values (couldn't let you take all the thunder on this one, plus you'll never pass a code review with one of those)

Comment: Good catch Smitty, to be honest I didn't know that one. Basic programming classes didn't teach me that ;).

Comment: Wouldn't `if(i != 100 && (i - 100) % 10 == 0) System.out.println();` work as well?

Comment: @JoshM Unfortunately not. Because it inserts a line break every time the number is divisible by 10, meaning it inserts a line break every 10 iterations. However, you can use: 
`if(i!=100 && (i - 100) % 300 == 0)`
 but in the event the numbers for comparison are different, let's say 5 and 11, this method will not work.